# How to break lines of text in equation?

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I have a problem with breaking lines in equation environment, can't really omit the text. I tried using `\mbox` and `\parbox` but they don't really give the effect I'm looking for.

example:

```
\documentclass[12 pt, leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, multicol, titlesec, amsthm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!...k_m!} xxxxxxxxx \{k_1,k_2,...,k_m\} xx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Where the `x`es represent text.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Use `multline` instead of `equation`. Or `multline*`.

Comment: aside from the request to provide a (non)working example, you should eliminate the blank lines from inside the `equation` environment.  you can use `\text{...}` (requires `amsmath`) to indicate the text.  to go beyond that, an example is really needed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Unfortunatly I have to use this environment for this one. I already have asmath loaded and also tried using \text. The problem is the text after the last equation is slightly too long and I would like it to be in a new line, aligned to left, sadly I can't break the line using \text.

Comment: Can you use `\intertext` (from the [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package) or `\shortintertext`?

Answer (score 3):

here are two possibilities.  for the first, the final text is taken outside the
equation environment.  for the second, the final text is split onto a separate
line of the display, and aligned to the left with the first line.  (i wasn't really
sure what you want.)

```
\documentclass[12 pt, leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, multicol, titlesec, amsthm}
\begin{document}
\noindent some text preceding the display
    \begin{equation}
    \text{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx } \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!...k_m!}
    \text{ xxxxxxxxx } \{k_1,k_2,...,k_m\}
    \end{equation}
    xx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.

\bigskip
\noindent if that isn't what you want, try this:
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    &\text{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx } \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!...k_m!}
      \text{ xxxxxxxxx } \{k_1,k_2,...,k_m\}\\
    &\text{xx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.}
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 0):

You can just put `\text`

```
\documentclass[12 pt, leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, multicol, titlesec, amsthm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \text{xxxx} \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!...k_m!} \text{xxxxx}\{k_1,k_2,...,k_m\} \text{xxxx}.
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If then you need to add space between text and math, use things like `\quad` or `\,` etc...